# Help with Binding tabcontrol that contains a treeview

Tags: silverlight, xaml

In a silverlight project i have a class:

```
class Foo{
  List<Bar> Bars;
  string BarName;
}
```

In my view model, I have:

```
List<Foo> Foos;
```

My TabControl is bound to Foos, and I'm using a `Converter` to convert my Foo class to a TabItem, with `Header = BarName`, and `Content = Bars`

My TabItem's content is just a TreeView, and I'd like to bind the TreeView's ItemSource to `Bars`

However I'm stuck trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TabControl's ContentTemplate should be DataTemplate with TreeView and

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate">
    <sdk:TreeView ItemsSource={Binding}/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Update:**

In code you can use template above:

```
yourTabItem.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Resources["ContentTemplate"];
```

Or without template:

```
yourTreeView.SetBinding(TreeView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Bars") { Source = yourSource });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my Converter class, how do I pass the list of items to the TreeView then?